# How to get flexbox item width dynamically including the gap value?

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, flexbox

I have created a dynamic grid system of 12 columns with flexbox "Like the one bootstrap using" using sass. I used "gap" of 1em between items but that affected the width of the items and let one of them wraps in the bottom. How to get the item width to include also the gap to get all the items

```
      <section className="container">
        <h1>This Is Section One</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="card col-4">
            <p>For Parteners</p>
          </div>
          <div className="card col-4">
            <p>For Students</p>
          </div>
          <div className="card col-4">
            <p>For Innovators</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

// Scss

      @for $i from 1 through $grid_columns{
        .col#{$modifier}-#{$i}{
          flex: 0 0 100%/$grid_columns * $i
        }

      .container{
        max-width: $grid_bp-md *1px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
        &-fluid{
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    
      .row{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        gap: 1em;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Account for `gap` size when calculating the size of your flex items.**

Your flex items aren’t aware of the `gap` set on the flex container. So you need to manually account for it when setting the `flex-basis` part of the `flex` property.

Luckily, [custom CSS properties](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and the [calc()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) function make this pretty straightforward.

You can calculate everything you need for you flex container, and then calculate the size of your flex item depending on how many columns it’s supposed to take up.

Here’s a working example:

```css
:root {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

section {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.flex-container__col-12 {
  --container-col-count: 12;
  --container-gap-count: calc(var(--container-col-count) - 1);
  --gap-size: 20px;
  --combined-gap-size: calc(var(--container-gap-count) * var(--gap-size));
  --col-size: calc(
    (100% - var(--combined-gap-size)) / var(--container-col-count)
  );

  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap-size);
}

.flex-item {
  --item-gap-count: calc(var(--item-col-count) - 1);
  --item-size: calc(
    var(--item-col-count) * var(--col-size) + var(--item-gap-count) *
      var(--gap-size)
  );
  flex: 0 0 var(--item-size);
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  --item-col-count: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  --item-col-count: 2;
}

.col-4 {
  --item-col-count: 4;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container__col-12">
  <div class="flex-item col-4">4 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-2">2 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-2">2 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-4">4 col</div>
</section>
<section class="flex-container__col-12">
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
  <div class="flex-item col-1">1 col</div>
</section>
```

As a side note, a dynamic grid system like this one could be achieved even more easily with [CSS Grid Layout](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works for me but I want also to set the gap dynamically. Thank you for your note too regarding the CSS Grid Layout

Comment: @MrGendy you can change the value of the `--gap-size` property and everything will recalculate automatically. You can change that value manually in CSS, or with JavaScript.